# retime_trajectory returns weird velocities and accelerations

Tags: moveit, python, ros-noetic

**OS:** Ubuntu Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
**ROS:** Noetic
**Robot:** Kinova Gen3 6DoF

To conduct reproducible studies I needed a program that executes specific routines always in the same way. Hence, I wrote a program that allows me to move the robot along the needed waypoints, plans the respective trajectories via Moveit with the needed constraints, and concatenates them into one comprehensive trajectory. The resulting objects gets pickled into a JSON file that can later be used to execute the specific routine.

First a bit of context:

I am using OMPL/RRTConnect planner with the following settings in `ompl_planning_pipeline.launch.xml`:

```
  <arg name="planning_adapters" value="default_planner_request_adapters/AddRuckigTrajectorySmoothing
                industrial_trajectory_filters/UniformSampleFilter
                default_planner_request_adapters/AddIterativeSplineParameterization
                   default_planner_request_adapters/FixWorkspaceBounds
                   default_planner_request_adapters/FixStartStateBounds
                   default_planner_request_adapters/FixStartStateCollision
                   default_planner_request_adapters/FixStartStatePathConstraints" />
```

I defined new soft limits that are higher than the default, but still lower than the hard limits:

```
joint_limits:
  $(arg prefix)joint_1:
    has_velocity_limits: true
    max_velocity: 0.82
    has_acceleration_limits: true
    max_acceleration: 1.68
  $(arg prefix)joint_2:
    has_velocity_limits: true
    max_velocity: 0.82
    has_acceleration_limits: true
    max_acceleration: 1.68
  $(arg prefix)joint_3:
    has_velocity_limits: true
    max_velocity: 0.82
    has_acceleration_limits: true
    max_acceleration: 1.68
  $(arg prefix)joint_4:
    has_velocity_limits: true
    max_velocity: 0.82
    has_acceleration_limits: true
    max_acceleration: 8.6
  $(arg prefix)joint_5:
    has_velocity_limits: true
    max_velocity: 0.82
    has_acceleration_limits: true
    max_acceleration: 8.6
  $(arg prefix)joint_6:
    has_velocity_limits: true
    max_velocity: 0.82
    has_acceleration_limits: true
    max_acceleration: 8.6
```

Since I want to be able to execute these trajectories with varying speed, during 'playback', I use the function `MoveGroupCommander.retime_trajectory()` with `algorithm="time_optimal_trajectory_generation"`. However, there is hardly any documentation about what it actually does. Moreover, when plotting the resulting joint positions, velocities and accelerations, the last two do not make any sense whatsoever. Here are the plots:

The left column shows the values before, the right column after I applied `retime_trajectory()` without scaling factors (i.e., velocity and acceleration percentage are both `1.0`). In the plots on velocities, the dotted green lines represent the joint speed limits as defined above, and in the plots on accelerations the dashed blue line represents the acceleration limits for joints 1-3.

[image: The left column shows the values before, the right column after I applied retime_trajectory() without scaling factors (i.e., velocity and acceleration percentage are both 1.0)]

There seems no connection between velocity and position in the right column. Velocity for joint 6 oscillates between minimum and maximum, however its position barely changes.
Furthermore, the acceleration values for joint 3 repeatedly exceeds the limit.
however, the trajectory on the right gets executed without problems, while the left one fails validation in the arm.

Now my question is: *Do velocity and acceleration values actually matter? And: does anyone know what retime_trajectory actually does?*

Comment: What documentation have you already read? Please edit your post to add some link(s).